# Firebase database modeling privacy settings

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

Hello I am using firebase realtime database and I implement privacy settings so a user can decide what information to show or hide.

This is my approach. I this a good way to structure data like this?

```
{<br>
  "friends" : {<br>
    "7BDcIre74IfE34DL1T1ZfzrZLcZ2" : {<br>
      "a3AiwvaXrHSHM05xBFq9X0TCBwi1" : {<br>
        "a3AiwvaXrHSHM05xBFq9X0TCBwi1" : true,<br>
        "rule1" : true<br>
      }<br>
    },<br>
    "a3AiwvaXrHSHM05xBFq9X0TCBwi1" : {<br>
      "7BDcIre74IfE34DL1T1ZfzrZLcZ2" : {<br>
        "7BDcIre74IfE34DL1T1ZfzrZLcZ2" : true,<br>
        "rule2" : true<br>
      }<br>
    }<br>
  },<br>
  "rules" : {<br>
    "rule1" : {<br>
      "showDate" : true,<br>
      "showName" : false<br>
    },<br>
    "rule2" : {<br>
      "showDate" : false,<br>
      "showName" : true<br>
    }<br>
  },<br>
  "users" : {<br>
    "7BDcIre74IfE34DL1T1ZfzrZLcZ2" : {<br>
      "Geburtsdatum" : "01.01.2000",<br>
      "name" : "Alex"<br>
    },<br>
    "a3AiwvaXrHSHM05xBFq9X0TCBwi1" : {<br>
      "Geburtsdatum" : "01.01.2000",<br>
      "Name" : "Peter"<br>
    },<br>
    "eAnWvNGh13N31nUEHszOzjUfL9d2" : {<br>
      "Geburtsdatum" : "01.01.2000",<br>
      "Name" : "Oskar"<br>
    }<br>
  }<br>
}<br>
```

Comment: Thank you I had problems styling the json.

Answer (score 0):

It's not. It can quickly get complicated and hard to implement if you would want to add more combinations of rules. You can create a model class for settings and under each friend user id you can create a privacy_settings node and under it you can set the values.

***Data Structure:***

`"a3AiwvaXrHSHM05xBFq9X0TCBwi1" : {
   "7BDcIre74IfE34DL1T1ZfzrZLcZ2" : {
     "privacy_settings": {
      "showDate" : false,
      "showName" : true
        }
      }
     }`

***Java Model Class:***

```
    import android.os.Parcelable;

public class PrivacySettings implements Parcelable
    {
        boolean showDate,showName;

        public PrivacySettings(boolean showDate, boolean showName)
            {
                this.showDate = showDate;
                this.showName = showName;
            }

        public boolean isShowDate()
            {

                return showDate;
            }

        public void setShowDate(boolean showDate)
            {
                this.showDate = showDate;
            }

        public boolean isShowName()
            {
                return showName;
            }

        public void setShowName(boolean showName)
            {
                this.showName = showName;
            }

        @Override
        public int describeContents()
            {
                return 0;
            }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
            {
                dest.writeByte(this.showDate ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
                dest.writeByte(this.showName ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
            }

        protected PrivacySettings(Parcel in)
            {
                this.showDate = in.readByte() != 0;
                this.showName = in.readByte() != 0;
            }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<PrivacySettings> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<PrivacySettings>()
            {
                @Override
                public PrivacySettings createFromParcel(Parcel source)
                    {
                        return new PrivacySettings(source);
                    }

                @Override
                public PrivacySettings[] newArray(int size)
                    {
                        return new PrivacySettings[size];
                    }
            };
    }
```